# SKIP and LIMIT operator in hyperledger composer not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Since fabric 1.1 doesnt have support for SKIP and LIMIT for pagination purpose. Whats the recommended way to handle it, as returning the whole result set might not be an option as it might be large in number. Also, looking on how to get the count?

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably seen in [this issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1015) this is not actively being worked on, but looking at [this JIRA Issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2809) for Fabric there is some possibility of getting some 'pagination' in Fabric 1.2.  Composer is unlikely to immediately take advantage of that 1.2 feature.

For the time being the way to reduce a large result set might be by using narrower criteria, or possibly date ranges.